# Drools update nested member attribute

Tags: object, nested, drools

I'm facing a problem while using Drools.
I try to update an attribute from a nested member. The update seems to work, but the when clause do not consider it.

I have 2 Obj object, sharing the same Cpt object.

```
Cpt cpt = new Cpt();

Obj obj1 = new Obj("obj1");
obj1.setComposant("R2");
obj1.counter = cpt;

Obj obj2 = new Obj("obj2");
obj2.setComposant("R2");
obj2.counter = cpt;

kSession.insert(obj2);
kSession.insert(obj1);
```

My rule is define as:

```
rule "R2"
    when
        m : Obj(composant == "R2" && counter.value == 0)
    then
        System.out.println(m.getName() + " " + m.getCounter().getValue());
        m.getCounter().increment();
end
```

I was expecting Obj1 to match the when clause, then update the value of the counter (from 0 to 1). So the Obj2 should not match the where clause.
But in fact, it does, even if the display is as I expected :

```
obj1 0
obj2 1
```

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

All reactions of the Drools Rule Engine with respect to changes in the set of facts require to be notified by using one of the extensions for the Right Hand Side language. You need to call update(f) for the modified fact object f, or you may use the modify(f){...} statement.

However... Changing a contained object X via the reference from fact A and telling the Engine that fact A has been modified will not make it see that fact B, also referencing X, has been changed as well.

This is where you should reconsider your design. Is it really necessary to have an X shared via references from A and B? Or: what about making X a fact and updating it? The latter may mean that you have to rewrite your rules, making the relation between Obj and Cpt visible on the left hand side. But, in my experience, it is usually better to have this than some complex mechanism propagating update notifications from some joint contained object to its parents.

**Edit** What I mean by "making the relation visible" is shown by the rule below:

```
rule "R2"
when
    Obj(composant == "R2", $counter: counter )
    $c: Cpt( this == $counter, value == 0)
then
    modify( $c ){ increment() }
end
```